# Disable RecyclerView itemAnimator for specific items

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

in recyclerView itemAnimator android, it is possible to disable/enable auto itemAnimation animation for specific adapter position, in real time?

Comment: i would also love to know if this is possible. I don't want to lose my onchange animations for everything, but i want it turned off for the views that are frequently updated.

Comment: I'ver tried extending the `DefaultItemAnimator` class and overriding either of, or both, of the `animateChanged` method and ignoring the items with the positions I don't want to change, but this seems to screw up something else with the RecyclerView and it will leave traces of the view in the background.

So i don't think it's the solution.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If you want to disable change animation you can provide payload for specific items instead

Comment: @NathanF. I added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59752516/1162154) 2 days ago. have you checked it?

Answer (score 3):

Try following code snippet:

```
val ignoreList = listOf<Int>(5, 6, 7)
recyclerView.itemAnimator = object : DefaultItemAnimator(){

    override fun canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
        if(ignoreList.contains(viewHolder.adapterPosition))
            return true;
        else
            return super.canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(viewHolder)
    }
}
```

You should modify `ignoreList` based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a simple way to do this either. It seems the animator is part of the layout manager and knows nothing about the items it's animating. So the only thing I could think of is call `notifyDataSetChanged` when I don't want an animation which will just refresh the whole RecyclerView.

I do this by extending `ListUpdateCallback` and overriding the `onMoved` method. It'll be easier to see in example code:

```
// my recyclerview is a list of events. You can click a checkbox to favourite an 
// event. When favourited, it moves to the top of the recyclerview. I want this move 
// animated but not vice versa. So when something is unfavourited, I don't want an 
// animation of the move when it goes back to its original position.
inner class CustomCallback(val newItems: List<Event>) : ListUpdateCallback {

    override fun onInserted(position: Int, count: Int) {
        notifyItemRangeInserted(position, count)
        Timber.d("NotificationCallback onInserted position: $position count: $count")
    }

    override fun onChanged(position: Int, count: Int, payload: Any?) {
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, count)
        Timber.d("NotificationCallback onChanged position: $position (${newItems[position].eventName}) count: $count")
    }

    override fun onMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
        if (newItems[toPosition].isFavourite == true) {
            Timber.d("item starred so animation")
            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
        } else if (newItems[toPosition].isFavourite == false) {
            Timber.d("item unstarred so no animation")
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        Timber.d("NotificationCallback onMoved from: $fromPosition (${newItems[fromPosition].eventName}) to: $toPosition (${newItems[toPosition].eventName})")
    }

    override fun onRemoved(position: Int, count: Int) {
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, count)
        Timber.d("NotificationCallback onRemoved position: $position count: $count")
    }
}
```

You call the custom ListUpdateCallback in your setItems or submitList or whatever method of your adapter.

```
// this.items is the member variable list of the items of the RV
fun setItems(newItems: List<Event>) {
    val result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(DiffUtilCallback(this.items, newItems))
    result.dispatchUpdatesTo(CustomCallback(newItems))
    this.items.clear()
    this.items.addAll(newItems)
}
```